# iterate, split, jump between numbers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im not sure how to ask this question, thats why I didnt found the answer yet... Im trying to iterate a chain number. I mean I created a for loop and instead for showing "30, 60, 90, 120..." I want to jump from 30 to 90 and from 90 to 180. I tried to split the chain but im not doing it right. This is my code:

```
writeIRFField: function (name, targetElement) {
  var $target = $(targetElement).split('1'),
    value, values = this.get(name) || [];

  $target.html('');
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    value = values[i] || 0; 
    $target.append('<label>' + ((i + 1) * 30) + ' ' + translator.getTranslation('days') + ' <input type="number" name="'+ name + '" value="' + value + '" min="0" step="0.01"></label>');
  }
},
```

Where should I split or make the "JUMP" between first value in the array and the third and so on...? (More easy to understand I guess would be like "I have this chain numer: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..." but I want to output: 1, 3, 5, 7..."

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear, but if you want to iterate in jumps use `i+=2` instead of `i++`

Comment: Oh awesome! this made it! Thank you!! and a little bit more tricky... if I want to make this jump? 30, 90, 180, 360? should make the "calculation" here i+=2 as well? I mean something like (i+=2)*2 or something like that? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Again - that's really not clear. I assume `30, 90, 180, 360` are values in an array? Or are you attempting to calculate them in a loop?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, this is correct! Thak you @RoryMcCrossan I can just keep jumping between the values or showing all of them. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want jump on only odd elements (indexes) like 1,3,5,...
You can do it in iteration:
instead of "`for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {...`" ,where i = 0,1,2,3
you can do like "`for(var i = 0; i < 4; i+=2) {...`", so i=0,2

Another possibility is to iterate over whole list, bit skip even numbers, numbers that divides by 2, like

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
       continue;//skip even undexes
    }
    value = values[i] || 0; 
    $target.append('<label>' + ((i + 1) * 30) + ' ' + translator.getTranslation('days') + ' <input type="number" name="'+ name + '" value="' + value + '" min="0" step="0.01"></label>');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I used the solution above :) instead of i++ im using i+2